# Stirling Approximation in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I want to plot to show how accurate is Stirling approximation in Mathematica by plotting the Percentage error against n. I want to take the value of n at the interval of 10 starting from 10 to 1000. So, I basically used the Listplot function to plot all these datas, which has been rather tedious. Is there any way simpler method to plot this approximation $\ln n!=n\ln n-n$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although n is allowed to take non integer values, you probably intend it to take only integer values, so this is a job for `DiscretePlot`

```
DiscretePlot[Log[n!]/(n Log[n] - n), {n, 10, 1000, 10}, 
      PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As an addendum, you can see how fast the relative error tends to zero with `Simplify[Series[1 - Log[n!]/(n Log[n] - n), {n, \[Infinity], 4}], n > 0]`

Comment: Can we manipulate the plot by using manipulate function ?

Comment: In principle, yes, but I don't see a useful free parameter to manipulate here.

Comment: There is no reason to restrict n to be an integer so you could also use `Plot`. `Manipulate[Plot[Log[n!]/(n Log[n] - n), {n, nmin, nmax}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], {{nmin, 10}, 10, 999, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{nmax, 1000}, nmin + 1, 1000, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Answer (score 5):

```
Plot[Log[n!] - (n Log[n] - n), {n, 1, 1000}]
```

[image]

shows the error between the two functions. You can divide by `n` to get percentage error...