# Generating terms of the Stirling series

Tags: series-expansion, special-functions

The Stirling series starts as follows:
$$n!=\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n}\sqrt{2\pi n}
\left\{1+\frac{1}{12n}+\frac{1}{288n^{2}}-\frac{139}{51840 n^{3}}-\frac{571}{2888380 n^{4}}+O\left(n^{-5}\right)\right\}.$$
Is it possible to use *Mathematica* to explicitly compute more terms?

Comment: Yes: `Series[n!, {n, ∞, k}]` computes `k` terms.

Comment: Related: [Plotting Stirling approximation error](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66766/stirling-approximation-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 12):

Using `Series` as suggested by Wolfgang Hintze:

```
Series[n!, {n, Infinity, 4}]/(Sqrt[2 π n] n^(n Exp[n])) // FullSimplify

(*Exp[(-1 - Log[1/n]) n + SeriesData[n, DirectedInfinity[1], {}, -1, 1, 1]^5] *
(SeriesData[n, Infinity, {1, 0, 1/12, 0, 1/288, 0, -139/51840, 0, -571/2488320},
            0, 10, 2]/n^(E^n*n))*)
```

Also, [Eric W. Weisstein](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsSeries.html) provides some documentation on Stirling series. His notebooks include code for an explicit computation, as well as this approach for Stirling coefficients:

```
PermutationCyclesD[r_, n_, k_] := 0 /; n <= k r - 1
PermutationCyclesD[r_, n_, 1] := (n - 1)!
PermutationCyclesD[r_, n_, k_] := PermutationCyclesD[r, n, k] =
   (n - 1) PermutationCyclesD[r, n - 1, k] +
   (-1)^(r - 1) Pochhammer[-(n - 1), r - 1] * PermutationCyclesD[r, n - r, k - 1]

StirlingCoefficient[0] := 1
StirlingCoefficient[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{k},
    Sum[(-1)^k PermutationCyclesD[3, 2 n + 2 k, k] / 2^(n + k)/(n + k)!, {k, 2 n}]]
```

Computing the first few terms, as given in your question:

```
Table[StirlingCoefficient[i], {i, 0, 4}]

(*{1, 1/12, 1/288, -139/51840, -571/2488320}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

Weisstein's method turns out to be a bit complicated when compared to the following procedure, due to [Marsaglia and Marsaglia](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2324749):

```
SetAttributes[marsagliaA, Listable];
marsagliaA[0] = marsagliaA[1] = 1;
marsagliaA[k_Integer?Positive] := marsagliaA[k] =
           (marsagliaA[k - 1] - Sum[j marsagliaA[j] marsagliaA[k - j + 1],
                                    {j, 2, k - 1}])/(k + 1)

m = 5; (* the asymptotic part *)
Sum[(2 k + 1)!! marsagliaA[2 k + 1] n^-k, {k, 0, m - 1}] + O[n, ∞]^m
   1 + 1/(12 n) + 1/(288 n^2) - 139/(51840 n^3) - 571/(2488320 n^4) + O[n, ∞]^5
```

Multiply by the `Sqrt[2 π n] (n/E)^n` factor and you have the Stirling series.

([Temme](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7dQko2CndYoC&pg=PA70) gives a similar but less efficient recurrence formula.)