# How can I use the Stirling's approximation to approximate factorials?

Tags: special-functions, expression-manipulation

I'd like to exploit Stirling's approximation during the symbolic manipulation of an expression. Essentially, I want replace `Factorial[n]` with `n^n E^-n Sqrt[2 \Pi n]` everywhere in a large expression.

How is it possible to achieve that?

---

As an example, I'd like to approximate a sum like this

$$
   \frac{n!}{(n+m_1)! (n-m_1)!}  + \frac{n!}{(n+m_2)! (n-m_2)!} + \frac{n!}{ (n+m_3)! (n-m_3)!}
   $$ 
to
    $$
\frac{F(n)}{F(n + m_1)Fun(n - m_1)} + \frac{F(n)}{F(n + m_2) F(n - m_2)} + \frac{F(n)}{F(n + m_3) F(n - m_3)},
$$
where
    $$
F(n) :=  \sqrt{2 \pi n} \, e^{-n} n^n
$$
is the Stirling approximation of $n!$.

Comment: Capital `N` is a built-in symbol, so better use `n` instead. Using `ReplaceAll` with the rule `Factorial[n] -> n^n E^-n  Sqrt[2 \[Pi] n]` should do, no?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! Maybe, but it seems it doesn't work if in the expression there are different factorials, say `n!` and `(n-m)!`. Or, is there a way to deal with that?

Comment: Normal[Series[n!, {n, Infinity, 0}]]//Simplify does the job. This is written in the help to n!.

Comment: Can you provide an example expression? All kinds of tricks available to manipulate combinatorial expressions.

Comment: How about using `/. Factorial[x_] -> x^x E^-x Sqrt[2 \[Pi] x]`?

Comment: It might actually be better to re-express everything in terms of `Gamma[]` (using `FunctionExpand[]` if necessary) and then use a replacement rule for Stirling. That way, you can handle `Beta[]`, `Binomial[]`, `FactorialPower[]`, `Pochhammer[]`...

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86712) might also be of interest.

Comment: The edit done by OP is noticed by me as addition.

Comment: @altroware, can you write out the actual sum you want? Not just the summand, it’s not clear what you are summing over.

Comment: apologies, I made a typo in the example.

Comment: Normal[Series[  n!/(n + m1)!/(n - m1)! + n!/(n + m2)!/(n - m2)! + 
   n!/(n + m3)!/(n - m3)!, {n, Infinity, 2}]] does the job, outputting $$e^{n (1-\log (n))} \left(\frac{-4 \sqrt{2} \text{m1}^2-4 \sqrt{2} \text{m2}^2-4 \sqrt{2} \text{m3}^2-\sqrt{2}}{8 \sqrt{\pi } n^{3/2}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{n}}\right) .$$

Comment: I'm still confused. I appreciate that `Series[n!, {n, Infinity, 0}] // Normal ` gives the correct answer for `n!`. Now I'd say that `n!/(n-m)!/(m+n)!` is approximated by `Fun[n_] := E^-n (1/n)^(-(1/2) - n) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]];Fun[n]/Fun[n + m1]/Fun[n - m1]`, but this is different than `Normal[Series[n!/(n + m1)!/(n - m1)!, {n, Infinity, 2}]]`, isn't it? Presumably also `n+m1` and `n+m2` are to set up $\to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  updated code as per comments below.
I believe this works:

```
Subscript[m, 1] = 2;
Subscript[m, 2] = 3;
Subscript[m, 3] = 4;
myf1[n_] = 
  n!/((n - Subscript[m, 1])! (n + Subscript[m, 1])!) + 
   n!/((n - Subscript[m, 2])! (n + Subscript[m, 2])!) + 
   n!/((n - Subscript[m, 3])! (n + Subscript[m, 3])!);
myf2[n_] = (myf1[n] /. (n_)! -> (Sqrt[2 Pi n] Exp[-n] n^n))
myf2[n] // TeXForm
myf1[100] // N
myf2[100] // N
```

$$
\frac {e^n (n - 4)^{\frac {7} {2} - n} n^{n + \frac {1} {2}} (n +     4)^{-n - \frac {9} {2}}} {\sqrt {2 \pi }} + \frac {e^ n (n - 3)^{\frac {5} {2} - n}    n^{n + \frac {1} {2}} (n + 3)^{-n - \frac {7} {2}}} {\sqrt {2 \pi }} + \frac {e^n (n - 2)^{\frac {3} {2} - n} n^{n + \frac {1} {2}}    (n + 2)^{-n - \frac {5} {2}}} {\sqrt {2 \pi }}
$$

```
2.923181964355016`*10^-158
2.925623558480809`*10^-158
```

Comment: Indeed it works. I'm not familiar with the double underscore `__`. Why is this necessary here?

Comment: The double (and triple) underscores mean take any expression (n, n+3, f(n), Sqrt[n], etc), and replace n in these expressions with the replacement value.   I think anyway.

Comment: No, double underscore means you can take/match a sequence of comma-separated items!  You can use a single underscore everywhere in the code above.  See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I updated my code above and indicated the changes.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, just use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series):

```
series = Series[
    n!/(n+m1)!/(n-m1)!+n!/(n+m2)!/(n-m2)!+n!/(n+m3)!/(n-m3)!,
    {n, Infinity, 2}
];
series //TeXForm
```

> $\exp \left((1-\log (n)) n+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^5\right)\right) \left(\frac{3
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{\left(-4 \sqrt{2} \operatorname{m1}^2-4 \sqrt{2}
>    \operatorname{m2}^2-4 \sqrt{2} \operatorname{m3}^2-\sqrt{2}\right) \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}}{8
>    \sqrt{\pi }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right)\right)$

If you want a normal expression, just use Normal:

```
Normal @ series //TeXForm
```

> $e^{n (1-\log (n))} \left(\frac{-4 \sqrt{2} \operatorname{m1}^2-4 \sqrt{2} \operatorname{m2}^2-4 \sqrt{2}
>    \operatorname{m3}^2-\sqrt{2}}{8 \sqrt{\pi } n^{3/2}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{n}}\right)$

Comment: Thanks! I commented on this in the comments to the questions.

Comment: This answer is very interesting, but I believe is incomplete:  I appreciate that `Series[n!, {n, Infinity, 0}] // Normal` gives the correct answer for $n!$. Now I'd say that $n!/(n-m)!/(m+n)!$ is approximated by `Fun[n]/Fun[n + m1]/Fun[n - m1]`, with `Fun[n_] := E^-n (1/n)^(-(1/2) - n) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]`. But this is different than `Normal[Series[n!/(n + m1)!/(n - m1)!, {n, Infinity, 2}]]` as this answer suggests, isn't it? What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing what you ask, illustrating the use of `Block`.
Define the expression in which to do the replacements

```
expr = Sum[n!/((n + m[i])! (n - m[i])!), {i, 1, 3}]
(* n!/((n - m[1])! (n + m[1])!) + n!/((n - m[2])! (n + m[2])!) + 
 n!/((n - m[3])! (n + m[3])!) *)
```

Do the replacement

```
Block[{Factorial = Sqrt[2 π #] Exp[-#] #^# &}, expr]
(* (E^n n^(
  1/2 + n) (n - m[1])^(-(1/2) - n + m[1]) (n + m[1])^(-(1/2) - n - 
   m[1]))/Sqrt[2 π] + (
 E^n n^(1/2 + n) (n - m[2])^(-(1/2) - n + m[2]) (n + m[2])^(-(1/2) - 
   n - m[2]))/Sqrt[2 π] + (
 E^n n^(1/2 + n) (n - m[3])^(-(1/2) - n + m[3]) (n + m[3])^(-(1/2) - 
   n - m[3]))/Sqrt[2 π] *)
```

Comment: For clarification: And this would work because `n!` is interpreted as `Factorial[n]` making the replacement become `(Sqrt[2 Pi #] Exp[-#] #^# &) [n]`? (Not sure if parenthesis necessary or not though)